# Arc length of another integral

Tags: integration

Im asked to find  the arc length of :

$$
\int_{-2}^{x}\sqrt{3w^4-1}dw
$$
where x is between -2 and -1.

Do I find the integral just as I would normally find it then find the arc length of that? Im a little confused on the notation I guess.

Comment: The way you have this stated the answer is $x \sqrt{3w^4-1}+2  \sqrt{3w^4-1}$. I think you might have a typo.

Comment: If you can do the integral, that is one way to do it.  Another way is to use the fundamental theorem of calculus (to find the arc length of f, you don't need f itself, just the derivative of f, which you can easily read off from the above).

Comment: That is also what I was thinking but wont the function change as the bounds change?

Comment: Where is the $t$ in your integral?

Comment: sorry typo its dw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $$f(x)=\int_{-2}^x\sqrt{3w^4-1}\,dw$$ is a curve in the plane. The formula for arc-length of a curve is $$L=\int_a^b\sqrt{(f'(x))^2+1}\,dx.$$ The fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that $$f'(x)=\sqrt{2x^4-1}.$$ Therefore, you need to solve the integral $$L=\int_{-2}^{-1}\sqrt{(\sqrt{3x^4-1})^2+1}\,dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula for the arc length:

$$\int_{-2}^{-1}\sqrt{1+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int_{-2}^{x}\sqrt{3w^4-1}\space\text{d}w\right]^2}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int_{-2}^{x}\sqrt{3w^4-1}\space\text{d}w\right]=\frac{\sqrt{-\left(3x^4-1\right)^2}}{\sqrt{1-3x^4}}$$

---

$$\int_{-2}^{-1}\sqrt{1+\left[\frac{\sqrt{-\left(3x^4-1\right)^2}}{\sqrt{1-3x^4}}\right]^2}\space\text{d}x=\int_{-2}^{-1}\sqrt{1+3x^4-1}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_{-2}^{-1}\sqrt{3x^4}\space\text{d}x=\sqrt{3}\int_{-2}^{-1}\sqrt{x^4}\space\text{d}x=\sqrt{3}\int_{-2}^{-1}x^2\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\sqrt{3}\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{-2}^{-1}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\left[x^3\right]_{-2}^{-1}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\left((-1)^3-(-2)^3\right)=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\left(-1--8\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\left(-1+8\right)=\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{3}=\frac{7}{\sqrt{3}}$$